# Foreach loop filtering on the API for show match form database

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, api

I am working on an API integration. Now I have a problem. 1st I am trying to show all specific city hotels, which city is having in my database. 1st FOREACH worked as well its search hotel by my database city, but on 2nd FOREACH I am trying to show 1st FOREACH city hotels show only match hotel which hotels matches from database and its not worked.

**My Task is: 1st search by city which city have on my database and 2nd time search in 1st time hotel and showed hotel only match my database hotel.**

**1st foreach:**

```
if($RowCount>0){
            foreach($Results as $Result){
                foreach($api_array as &$value){
                    if($Result['county'] == $value['address']['city']){ 
                        $final_array[] = $value; 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
```

**2nd foreach:**

```
foreach($final_array as &$display){
            var_dump($display);
            if($Result['hotel'] == $display['property_name']){ 
                $final_array2[] = $display; 
            }  
        }
```

**var_dump "$display" its worked well and showing match city with database:** There `property_name = "Jurys Inn Cork"` have my database. How can I show only this Jurys Inn Cork array.

```
array (size=12)
  'property_code' => string 'YXORKOHH' (length=8)
  'property_name' => string 'Oriel House Hotel' (length=17)
  'location' => 
    array (size=2)
      'latitude' => float 51.88801
      'longitude' => float -8.60129
  'address' => 
    array (size=4)
      'line1' => string 'Ballincollig' (length=12)
      'city' => string 'Cork' (length=4)
      'postal_code' => string '00000' (length=5)
      'country' => string 'IE' (length=2)

array (size=12)
  'property_code' => string 'UIORK970' (length=8)
  'property_name' => string 'Cork Airport Hotel' (length=18)
  'location' => 
    array (size=2)
      'latitude' => float 51.85213
      'longitude' => float -8.48631
  'address' => 
    array (size=3)
      'line1' => string 'Cork Airport' (length=12)
      'city' => string 'Cork' (length=4)
      'country' => string 'IE' (length=2)

array (size=12)
  'property_code' => string 'JIORKCOR' (length=8)
  'property_name' => string 'Jurys Inn Cork' (length=14)
  'location' => 
    array (size=2)
      'latitude' => float 51.89956
      'longitude' => float -8.46428
  'address' => 
    array (size=4)
      'line1' => string 'Andersons Quay' (length=14)
      'city' => string 'Cork' (length=4)
      'postal_code' => string '00000' (length=5)
      'country' => string 'IE' (length=2)
```

**full code:**

```
    foreach($array as $api_array){
        $final_array = array(); 
        $Results = $wpdb->get_results( "select * FROM hotels where county = '$countyname'",ARRAY_A );
        $RowCount  =  $wpdb->num_rows;

        if($RowCount>0){
            foreach($Results as $Result){
                foreach($api_array as &$value){
                    if($Result['county'] == $value['address']['city']){ 
                        $final_array[] = $value; 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
        foreach($final_array as &$display){
            if($Result['hotel'] == $display['property_name']){ 
                $final_array2[] = $display; 
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see __4__ `foreach`es here. Which one is 1st and which one is 2nd?

Comment: @u_mulder I have edited.

Comment: replace the &$display to $display

Answer (score 0):

Replace this on your 2nd foreach loop.

```
       foreach($Results as $Result){
            foreach($final_array as &$display){
                if($Result['hotel'] == $display['property_name']){ 
                    $final_array2[] = $display;
                }  
            }
        }
```